# Если в WordPress терминам нужно добавить много полей ACF, то как это лучше сделать?

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, php7, acf

У кастомной таксономии очень много терминов.
И для каждого из этих терминов мне нужно, чтобы были несколько произвольных полей ACF (картинка, цвет, 2 поля редактора WordPress).

Чтобы добавить эти поля к терминам, рассматриваю два варианта:

1)  Создать произвольный тип записи, присвоить им нужные поля ACF, сделать привязку записи к термину (через поле ACF) и там же описать термин. То есть, URL этих записей на сайте нигде использоваться не будет, они будут просто для того, чтобы хранить информацию и затем в шаблонах терминов, перебирая эти записи в цикле, выводить нужно информацию.

Но у меня такой вопрос, насколько будет адекватным такой вариант, не будет ли пагубным то, что существуют записи, URL которых нигде не используется, может ли это негативно повлиять на поисковую оптимизацию?

2)  Второй вариант – это на странице настроек ACF сделать повторитель, и там описывать термины. Затем также само через цикл в шаблоне термина перебирать эго и выводить нужную информацию. Но этот вариант не совсем удобен будет, так как очень много пунктов будет и сложно будет ориентироваться, искать нужный

Что можете посоветовать в таком случаи?

Comment: А что такое "термины" в wp?

Comment: @РашенБеар вы вроде давно тут... Это как рубрики у записи. Категория - это стандартная таксономия. У неё могут быть термины (рубрики) типа "Спорт, Политика, Бизнес". Пользователь может создать свою кастомную таксономию, например, "Дома". В ней могут быть термины "Деревянные, Каменные, Вигвамы". Постам кастомного типа можно присвоить термин таксономии и выводить эти посты, скажем, по разделу "Деревянные дома".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привязал ACF к терминам. У термов же есть `wp_termmeta`, поэтому это оказывается можно легко сделать.